# How to find users directly or indirectly entrance to my webpage page by php for statistics?

Tags: php, statistics, visitor-statistic, web-statistics

I want to know how many user enter to my webpage **directly** and how many by 
**search engines** or **other sites**.

How i can do that?

Comment: www.alexa.com provides information about websites including Internet Traffic Stats and Metrics, Related Links

Comment: i know, but i want to implement it by my self.

Comment: What database system are you using? I've done this myself. I'll post the code when I get home if you want.

Comment: @user2857863 Sure, how can I send it to you? I use MySql as well.

Comment: send it to "h.hmohseni@gmail.com"

Comment: Tnx a lot Patrick Geyre :)

Answer (score 2):

Your obvious choice would be [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), although not a "PHP" solution, it should give you all of the information you need.

It's widely supported across the internet and is pretty easy to use too!

Here's the "traffic sources" page:

[image]

Comment: I know, but i want to implement it by my self.

Comment: and reinvent the wheel?

Comment: No, but i have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google analytics 
http://www.google.co.in/analytics/
You can monitor everything on your web page using google analytics

Comment: i know, but i want to implement it by my self

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']'
```

You can then store this in a database.

It will be blank if the end user:

- The address is entered into the URL bar itself
- Visited by bookmark
- Switching of protocols (e.g. https to http)
- Software installed that removes all referrer from requests

Google analytics:

How Does Google Analytics Collect Data?

The data that Google Analytics uses to provide all the information in your reports comes from these sources:

The HTTP request of the visitor
Browser/system information
First-party cookies
: You can get these all from the $_SERVER global.

Comment: Not reliable because not all user-agents support it.

Comment: So you want to track referrals to your site, without using `$_SERVER['http_referer'];` or outside tools and you want it to work with all browsers. I feel you're going to be disappointed.